# Object destructing in if-condition results in global variable?

Tags: javascript, scope, variable-assignment, destructuring, hoisting

Can someone explain to me why I can access "m" in global scope in the following scenario:

```
const a = {m: 'beeb'};


const magic = function topLevel () {
   function lowerLevel() {
    if ({m} = a ) { 
      console.log('in lowerLevel-func: ', m);
    }
  }

  lowerLevel();
}


magic();

console.log('in global', m);
```

and here is [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kaqueahg/20/)

Edit:  Just to clarify, I am not using this anywhere, I was just wondering how it was possible. Now I know, thanks!

Comment: Because you're *assigning* instead of *comparing* by using a single `=` in your `if`

Comment: use `==` or `===` in if

Comment: Basically you're testing if a is null.

Comment: What was this statement even supposed to do? Did you mean `if (m)`, or `if (m.a)`, or something else?

Comment: Always use strict mode!

Comment: `whatever=a` returns `a`, so `{m}=a` doesn't say you anything about `a.m`, even if you declare `m` properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If you assign a value to a variable that has not been declared, it will automatically become a GLOBAL variable. And since you are doing `=(Assigning)` instead of `==(compairing)`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <p>
    If you assign a value to a variable that has not been declared, it will automatically become a GLOBAL variable:
  </p>

  <p id="demo"></p>

  <script>
    myFunction();

    // code here can use carName as a global variable
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "I can display " + carName;

    function myFunction() {
      carName = "Volvo";
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

[References](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp)

Also Read [What is the scope of variables in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript)

Comment: This states a general rule of the language, it doesn't answer this specific question.

Comment: Yeah, I am aware of scopes etc. I just did not know that undeclared variable becomes part of global scope automatically. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It happens because you never explicitly declared (with `var`, `let` or `const` statements) `m` variable, so it becomes a property of the global `Window` object (that's why you can access it from anywhere in your code). It would be the explanation if you intended to assign a value to `m` inside if statement and not to compare.

Note that if you do the same in strict mode, you won't get such behaviour as it doesn't allow to use variables that have never been declared.

Comment: Ahh, that explains it...I was not aware that undeclared variable goes automatically to global. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You observe this behaviour because you are making an assignment to a previously non declared variable **and** you are executing your code in non-strict mode.

The line:

```
if ({m} = a ) {
```

Is effectively an assignment of the `m` field of the variable `a` to a variable `m`. Now because `m` has not been previously declared nor exists in the global scope two things can happen:

- in non strict mode this degenerate into an assignement to `window['m']` which makes it available globally
- in strict mode you get a reference error.

Imo the last behaviour should be the behaviour you should be targeting as it is (imo) the least "surprising" one.